# Whats the most efficient way to update a variable in a file?

Tags: awk, filesystems, variable, performance

Short Question: Whats the most efficient way to update a single numbered variable in a file?

Long Question: I'm looking at the output of a security program (fail2ban) which logs which hosts have been added to the linux firewall for various reasons. fail2ban allows custom actions [1] to be performed when an offender is detected, and I intend to simply increment a variable in a file. This file will be used later via different server that accesses it to display the number at an as-yet unknown interval.

I intend to use awk/gawk to load the file, take the variable, add one, then save it in place.

To save excessive disk writes and CPU usage on a VPS, what's the most effect way that I can, when something is registered in fail2ban, take whatever number is in a file, increment it and write it back to that same file in the most efficient way possible (either Disk IO, memory usage or CPU utilisation).

[1] - Fail2Ban provides the following actions, where command line parameters can be added. This is where I hope to add my efficient snippet.

```
[Definition]
actionstart =
actionstop =
actioncheck =
actionban = awk...
actionunban = awk..
```

*Bonus points if the unban can be run and is the opposite (decrements the number) in a just-as-efficient manner

Comment: [edit] your question to provide a MCVE with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you've tried so far so we can help you. See [ask].

Comment: Yes, we can't help you parse data if you don't show us what data to parse. Please add an example input file and the output you would want from that example.

Answer (score 2):

The super fast way of incrementing a number in a file, could be:

`awk -F, '{$0=$0+1}1' OFS=, failtoban.txt >tmp; mv tmp failtoban.txt`

and for decrementing the number you can do:

`awk -F, '{$0=$0-1}1' OFS=, failtoban.txt >tmp; mv tmp failtoban.txt`

But, what this is not taking into account is the situation, where you have too fast increments or decrements at the same time.

Actually after doing some small changes, you can do this instead, which is modifying the file inplace:

Increment:

`awk -i inplace '{ print $0=$0+1 }' failtoban.txt`

Decrement:

`awk -i inplace '{ print $0=$0-1 }' failtoban.txt`

**As per Ed Morton's comment, it can all be done smarter:**

Increment:

`awk -F, '{++$0}1' OFS=, failtoban.txt >tmp; mv tmp failtoban.txt`

Decrement:

`awk -F, '{--$0}1' OFS=, failtoban.txt >tmp; mv tmp failtoban.txt`

Increment:

`awk -i inplace '{ print ++$0 }' failtoban.txt`

Decrement:

`awk -i inplace '{ print --$0 }' failtoban.txt`

Comment: Always do `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` rather than `cmd file > tmp; mv tmp file` as the latter will potentially wipe out your input file if `cmd` fails for any reason. When you say `reversing` above you mean `decrementing`. You can do `$0++` and `$0--` rather than `$0=$0+1` and `$0=$0-1`.

Comment: @EdMorton as per Ubuntu 20.04 I don't see ```$0++``` and ```$0--``` working in the print style.

Comment: To print the result in the same statement as you increment the variable you'd need to pre-increment it, not post-incremenet it, so `print ++$0` and `print --$0`.